# Pasting Array into Range Using Transpose Function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, paste

I'm attempting to transpose an array into a range:

```
Sub transposearray()

Dim letters As Variant
Dim sht As Workbook
Set sht = Workbooks("report 7-16.xlsx")

letters = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")

    sht.Range("AB1:AB6").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(letters)


End Sub
```

but when I run this code I receive message saying 'run time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `sht` is set to a workbook. You need the worksheet also, i.e. `sht.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a worksheet variable. Try this (edit the sheet name/index as necessary):

```
Sub transposearray()

Dim letters As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("report 7-16.xlsx")

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = wb.Sheets(1)

letters = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
sht.Range("AB1:AB6").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(letters)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was something simple I was overlooking like this :)